# Is there a way with gcloud client to define a budget for a project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm setting up a a script in order to automatize developing stuff over google cloud infrastructure. Now I need to define a budget for a specific project. Can I define a budget programmatically with gcloud client from command line? Because from the documents seems that this feature is not already enable. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available. Some options you might consider.

1. [Setup budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets)
2. [Programmatic budget notification](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify)
3. [Set spending limits for App Engine standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Billable_Resource_Quotas) and [setting alarms for App Engine flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/managing-projects-apps-billing#creating_budgets_and_setting_alerts)